# How to run a function with an infinite loop after rendering a page in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm writting a Django web application which will work as a tweet bot. At some point in the app the user will have to fill up a form which will decide what kind of tweets will be posted. When the user submits the form I want to render a web page to inform the user that the app is running in the background and after that I want to run the infinite loop that actually do the tweeting. My question is, how can I render a web page (from the views file) and then run the actual function (which lives in another file)?

Passing the info of the form to the posting view:

```
random_object = Random.objects.create(quotes=quotesSwitch, jokes=jokesSwitch, chuckNorris=chukNorrisSwitch,
                    movieReview=movieReviewsSwitch, periodicityNumber=periodicityNumber, periodicity=periodicity)
atributes = {
    'random_object': random_object
}
return render(request, 'posting.html', {'random_object': atributes})
```

and the posting view:

```
def posting(request):
    obj = Random(request.POST)
    random_func(obj) #This is the function with the infinite loop

    return render(request, 'posting.html')
```

Comment: When you say "another file", do you mean you will be starting a separate Python process, or just that the function is imported?  You can certainly spin off a new process to run forever.  You can also spin off a thread, but if your web application stops, so will the thread.

Comment: The function is imported. I want to execute a function with an infinite loop that is in other python file but in the same app.

Comment: Then as I said, you either spin off a thread, or you use `multiprocessing` to spin off another process.